# AS3 - variables undefined

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm now creating a Air for android using flash cc.
In a for loop, i write like this. (this is only a part of the whole)

```
var six1=Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs)+String(mcb)].currentFrame
var six2=Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+1)+String(mcb)].currentFrame
var six3=Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+2)+String(mcb)].currentFrame
var six4=Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+3)+String(mcb)].currentFrame
var six5=Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+4)+String(mcb)].currentFrame
var six6=Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+5)+String(mcb)].currentFrame
```

I have 36 movieclip total: mc_11, mc_12... mc_16 to mc_61, mc_62...mc_66
When variables "mcs" and "mcb" in for loop is 6 and 6 respectively, then in line 6, the movieclip name will be [mc_611], and it will be undefined, and error pops up.
But if i just want the result of "six6" being undefined and no error pops up, what can i do??  (because "six6" being undefined will not affect the following code)
.
Pls help! thanks u !!!

Comment: not enough info provided here

Comment: Please show more code and a more detailed explanation of the problem. What you are expecting to see and what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can try to test if your object exists or not before accessing currrentFrame propertie
 
ex:

```
var six6 = Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+5)+String(mcb)] ? Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+5)+String(mcb)].currentFrame : udefined;</code>
```

or :

```
var six6 = undefined;
if( Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+5)+String(mcb)] )
{
    six6 = Object(root)["mc_"+String(mcs+5)+String(mcb)].currentFrame;
}
```